# Problems with Autocompletetextview and SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, autocomplete, simplecursoradapter

I am having real trouble with this and I was wondering I could get some help.  I have the following code.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Simple notes database access helper class. Defines the basic CRUD operations
 * for the notepad example, and gives the ability to list all notes as well as
 * retrieve or modify a specific note.
 * 
 * This has been improved from the first version of this tutorial through the
 * addition of better error handling and also using returning a Cursor instead
 * of using a collection of inner classes (which is less scalable and not
 * recommended).
 */
public class recoverAnimalDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.recover.foundanimal/databases/";
    public static final String KEY_BIRDGROUP = "birdgroup";
    public static final String KEY_BIRD_LATINNAME = "birdlatinname";
    public static final String KEY_BIRD_COMMONNAME = "birdcommonname";
    public static final String KEY_BIRD_REGIONFOUND = "birdregionfound";
    public static final String KEY_BIRD_SUBREGION = "birdsubregion";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    private static final String TAG = "RECOVERAnimalDBHelper";
    private static SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "recoveranimals.sqlite";
    private static final String DATABASE_BIRD_SPECIES_TABLE = "birds";

    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    /**
     * Database creation sql statement
     */
    private static final String CREATE_BIRD_SPECIES_TABLE =

        "create table "+DATABASE_BIRD_SPECIES_TABLE+" ("+KEY_ROWID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_BIRDGROUP+" text not null, "
        + KEY_BIRD_LATINNAME+" text not null, "
        +KEY_BIRD_COMMONNAME+" text not null, "
        +KEY_BIRD_REGIONFOUND+" text not null, "
        +KEY_BIRD_SUBREGION +" text not null); ";

    protected static Context mCtx = null;



    public recoverAnimalDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mCtx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //          }
        //           if (!db.isReadOnly())
        //          {
        //            // Enable foreign key constraints
        //            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
        //          }
        //            db.execSQL(CREATE_BIRD_SPECIES_TABLE);
        //            fillDatabase(db);
    }

    public void createDatabase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!dbExist) {
            this.getWritableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }else {
            this.getWritableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        mDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private static boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }
    private void fillDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.beginTransaction();
        Resources currResource = mCtx.getResources();
        Field[] values = R.array.class.getDeclaredFields();
        String[] birds = currResource.getStringArray(R.array.birdfamilies);
        HashMap<String, String[]> birdFamToKey = new HashMap<String, String[]>(birds.length);
        for(String bird : birds) {
            String[] brdtyps = bird.split("b1234b");
            birdFamToKey.put(brdtyps[brdtyps.length-1], brdtyps);
        }
        String[] specBird = null;
        String birdGroup = null;
        for(Field v : values) {
            if(birdFamToKey.containsKey(v.getName())) {
                try {
                    specBird = currResource.getStringArray(v.getInt(null));
                    birdGroup = birdFamToKey.get(v.getName())[0];
                } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                    Log.w(TAG,""+v.getName()+" was not found in keyset with error: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    continue;
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Log.w(TAG,""+v.getName()+" was not found in keyset with error: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    continue;
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    Log.w(TAG,""+v.getName()+" was not found in keyset with error: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(specBird != null && birdGroup != null) {
                for(String brdspc : specBird) {
                    if(brdspc.contains("Family"))
                        continue;
                    String[] brdspcarr = brdspc.split("b1234b");
                    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
                    try {
                        initialValues.put(KEY_BIRDGROUP,birdGroup);
                        initialValues.put(KEY_BIRD_LATINNAME, brdspcarr[1]);
                        initialValues.put(KEY_BIRD_COMMONNAME, brdspcarr[0]);
                        if(brdspcarr.length>2) {
                            initialValues.put(KEY_BIRD_REGIONFOUND, brdspcarr[2]);
                            if(brdspcarr.length >3)
                                initialValues.put(KEY_BIRD_SUBREGION , brdspcarr[3]);
                            else
                                initialValues.put(KEY_BIRD_SUBREGION , "");
                        }else {
                            initialValues.put(KEY_BIRD_REGIONFOUND, "");
                            initialValues.put(KEY_BIRD_SUBREGION , "");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage()+"\nCAUSE: "+e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    db.insertOrThrow(DATABASE_BIRD_SPECIES_TABLE, null, initialValues);
                }
            }
            specBird = null;
        }
        db.endTransaction();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
        //                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        //            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DATABASE_BIRD_SPECIES_TABLE);
        //            onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private static void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        AssetManager assetManager = mCtx.getAssets();
        InputStream myInput = assetManager.open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(mDb != null)
            mDb.close();
        super.close();
    }


    public void resetTables() {
        this.onUpgrade(mDb, 1, 1);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all birds in the database
     * 
     * @return Cursor over all notes
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllAnimals() {

        Cursor mCursor =  mDb.query(DATABASE_BIRD_SPECIES_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_BIRDGROUP,KEY_BIRD_LATINNAME,
                KEY_BIRD_COMMONNAME, KEY_BIRD_REGIONFOUND,KEY_BIRD_SUBREGION}, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    /**
     * Returns all unique macroclasses of animals
     * 
     * @return Cursor to all bird types
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllAnimalTypes() {
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_BIRD_SPECIES_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_BIRDGROUP}, null,null,null,null,KEY_BIRDGROUP+" ASC",null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    /** Returns all animals species that mach an animal type
     * 
     * @return Cursor pointing to all animal species matching the bird type selected
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllAnimalSpecies(String animalType) {
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_BIRD_SPECIES_TABLE,new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_BIRD_COMMONNAME},KEY_BIRDGROUP+" = ?",new String[] {animalType},null,null,KEY_BIRD_COMMONNAME+" DESC");
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor positioned at the animal that matches the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of animal to retrieve
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching animal, if found
     * @throws SQLException if note could not be found/retrieved
     */
    public Cursor fetchAnimal(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_BIRD_SPECIES_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_BIRDGROUP,KEY_BIRD_LATINNAME,
                    KEY_BIRD_COMMONNAME, KEY_BIRD_REGIONFOUND,KEY_BIRD_SUBREGION}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    public boolean isOpen() {
        if( mDb != null && mDb.isOpen())
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAnimalTypePartialMatching(String partialmatch) {
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_BIRD_SPECIES_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_BIRDGROUP,KEY_ROWID}, KEY_BIRDGROUP+" LIKE ?",
                new String[] {partialmatch},null,null,KEY_BIRDGROUP+" DESC",null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAnimalSpecificPartialMatching(String animalType, String partialmatch) {
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_BIRD_SPECIES_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_BIRD_COMMONNAME,KEY_ROWID},
                KEY_BIRDGROUP+" = ? AND "+KEY_BIRD_COMMONNAME+" LIKE ?",new String[] {animalType,partialmatch},null,
                null,KEY_BIRD_COMMONNAME+" DESC");

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAnimalSpeciesParitalMatching(String partialmatch) {
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_BIRD_SPECIES_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_BIRD_COMMONNAME,KEY_ROWID},
                KEY_BIRD_COMMONNAME+" LIKE ?",new String[] {partialmatch},null,
                null,KEY_BIRD_COMMONNAME+" DESC");

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public Cursor query(String[] m_projection, String selct, String[] args,
            String m_sortOrder) {
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(this.DATABASE_BIRD_SPECIES_TABLE, m_projection, selct, args, null, null, m_sortOrder);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
}
```

The Code that uses this is:

```
AutoCompleteTextView actvMainType = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.animalMainTypeTB);
            actvMainType.setMaxLines(1);
            SimpleCursorAdapter scaSpecTyp = new SimpleCursorAdapter(cntxt,R.layout.simpleautocompletelayout,mCursorMainType,
                    new String[] {recoverAnimalDBHelper.KEY_BIRDGROUP}, new int[] {R.id.autocompleteTxt});
            scaSpecTyp.setStringConversionColumn(
                    mCursorMainType.getColumnIndexOrThrow(recoverAnimalDBHelper.KEY_BIRDGROUP));
            scaSpecTyp.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

                public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                    String partialItemName = null;
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        partialItemName = constraint.toString();
                    }
                    return rdbHelper.fetchAnimalTypePartialMatching(partialItemName);
                }
            });

            actvMainType.setAdapter(scaSpecTyp);
            actvMainType.setThreshold(1);
```

I am trying to get this database to work and I can't seem to get the autocomplete to work.  Any suggestions?

Thanks so much!
Jon

Comment: Can you please add the code which is using this ?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader

Comment: Where and how did you declare rdbHelper and mCursorMainType. Also where do you write the method fetchAnimalTypePartialMatching and what does it do?

Comment: the rdbHelper is the main class detailed above (where I also generate the cursor function).  fetchAnimalTypePartial allows me to match partial text - hence the like function implementation that I needed to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this site: http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-simpler-autocompletetextview-with-simplecursoradapter/  I was able to solve it very simply.  My code was very sloppy basically and I wasn't using the LIKE terms correctly.  Thanks all!

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!! stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader